# How can I parse a varchar string into three columns, Year, Month and Day

Tags: sql, sql-server, parsing

I figured one way to solve my poorly formatted table would be to parse the "date" column in to three columns after which i can properly run queries on. The date format is 'ddmmmyyyy' style (31DEC2013).

How can I parse this string into three distinct columns "day", "month", "year".

Thanks in advance

Comment: One thing no one has mentioned so far is that when you store dates in a varchar field, the chance of having something that is NOT a valid date in the field is high. Before trying to convert you should make sure that all your values are valid dates.

Comment: In SQL Server 2012 and up, you can easily use `TRY_CONVERT()` to simply ignore values that can't be converted. In earlier versions, you'd need to identify them first using `ISDATE()` perhaps, and somehow prevent those rows from being considered (a simple `WHERE` clause is often not enough to avoid issues). The best fix, of course, is to stop storing these non-date strings this way in the first place - use a proper data type to store dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DATEPART command can do that for you. For example:

```
select datepart(day, '31DEC2013')
select datepart(month, '31DEC2013')
select datepart(year, '31DEC2013')
```

I would recommend just leaving your date in one column, and using datepart on the fly in your queries.

Comment: @midiman Make sure you're using single quotes, not double quotes. Single quotes are for strings. Double quotes are for column names.

Comment: Please [don't use lazy shorthands](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations) for the date parts

Comment: apologies, it was my error. i didn't include the from clause! i'm still learning, i promise!! Thank you so much this worked.

Comment: Also make sure the language is english - not all cultures call December December.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to get your data from one WRONG type to another WRONG type. It is a date value and you should use appropriate data type for it which is `DATE` or `DATETIME`.

Saving this data with appropriate data type will give you access to many datetime functions for data manipulations.

### Test Data

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(String_Month VARCHAR(9))
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES 
 ('31DEC2013')
,('26NOV2013')
,('22SEP2013')
,('31DEC2013')
,('31DEC2013')
```

### Query

```
SELECT CAST(  CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, String_Month) AS VARCHAR(4))  + '-'
            + CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, String_Month)  AS VARCHAR(2))+ '-'
            + CAST(DATEPART(DAY, String_Month)  AS VARCHAR(2)) AS DATE) AS Result
FROM @TABLE
```

### Result

```
Result
2013-12-31
2013-11-26
2013-09-22
2013-12-31
2013-12-31
```

Comment: this is definitely way more than i asked! thank you so much for the insight. Quick question, is there a way i can properly insert the result of that query in a new column formatted as a date? @m.ali

Comment: If DATEPART recognises the format of `String_Month`, why all that fuss with extracting and concatenating bits and converting the result when you can simply do `CAST(String_Month AS date)`?

Comment: @AndriyM silly me, didnt know SQL Server recognise it as DATE :) thanks for pointing this out though :)

Comment: I didn't know that either but decided to check it before commenting. I actually was going to suggest this double conversion initially: `CAST(CAST(String_Month AS datetime) AS date)` – you'll agree that that would still be much simpler.

Comment: Still CAST to datetime and then Date would be better I think, as compare to what I have done (multiple string manipulations) :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
select datepart(day, '31DEC2013') as [day], 
       datepart(month, '31DEC2013') as [month],
       datepart(year, '31DEC2013') as [year]
```

Comment: Please [don't use lazy shorthands](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations) for the date parts

Comment: @Lamak:- Updated my as well as CheeseInPosition answer. Thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are storing your value as a string you either need to cast it into a DataTime and then use DatePart. Or use substring on your string value

[DatePart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx):

```
select  datepart(DAY, cast([date] as datetime)) as [day], 
        datepart(MONTH, cast([date] as datetime)) as [month],
        datepart(YEAR, cast([date] as datetime)) as [year]
```

[Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx):

```
select  SUBSTRING([date], 0, 2) as [day], 
        SUBSTRING([date], 2, 3) as [month],
        SUBSTRING([date], 5, 4) as [year]
```

Comment: [Why D instead of DAY, M instead of MONTH, and of all things YYYY instead of YEAR](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx)?

Comment: I thought it would make more sense to the poster in that format since he posted his format string.

Comment: Please spell these things out - as I describe in my post, for the exact reason you probably used `YYYY` - `Y` doesn't do what you expect, now, does it?